# same program is much slower on a supposedly better machine

Tags: throughput

When running the same application on two different machines, I see one is much slower but it ought to be the faster of the two. This is a compute bound application with a thread pool. The threads do not communicate with each other nor externally. The application reads from disk at the beginning (for a fraction of a second) and writes to disk at the end (for a fraction of a second).

The program repeatedly runs a simulation on a deterministically changing set of inputs. Since the inputs are identical the outputs can be compared and they are in fact identical. The only difference is the elapsed time. There is an object that I recall is "shared" in the sense that all threads read from it but my recollection is that this is strictly read-only. The work threaded is homogeneous.

`Dual machine`: 2 core / 4 thread machine, 2.53 GHz, 3MB cache, 8GB RAM, passmark.com benchmark is approximately 2100, my application's thread pool size set to 4, JVM memory high water mark was 2.8 GB, elapsed time is 47 minutes

`Quad machine`: 4 core / 8 thread machine, 2.2 GHz to 3.1 GHz, 6MB cache, 8GB RAM, passmark.com benchmark is approximately 6000, my application's thread pool size set to 8, JVM memory high water mark was 2.8GB, elapsed time 164 minutes

Another comparison:

`Dual machine`: thread pool size set to 2, elapsed time 98 minutes * Could be less. Please see the footnote.

`Quad machine`: thread pool size set to 2, elapsed time 167 minutes

*Probably should be less than 98 minutes since I was also playing an audio file. This means the anomaly is worse than this result makes it appear.

The `jvisualvm` profiles seem similar but due to what seem to be profiler glitches I haven't gotten much use from it. I'm looking for suggestions on where to look.

Both machines are Ubuntu 14.04.3 and on Java 8.

Comment: Was it profiling or sampling ? You could try a demo version of yourkit profiler to get a second opinion. Is the JVM configured identically ? Both on server / client JVM ? Same bitness ? Some code runs faster on x64

Comment: Are those passmark results based on your measurements on your hardware?  Or something you got from the internet / the vendor?  I'm thinking they could be incorrect for your actual hardware.  Also not that a single benchmark number does not reflect differences in CPU internal architectures, instruction sets, etcetera.

Comment: Marged, it was the profiling result. Sampling also looked similar until the crashing. Both are 64 bit, Both are with the same -Xms -Xmx setting.

Comment: Stephen C, the passmark.com results are not mine. They're just what is reported on the website. Both machines are laptops.

Comment: Many laptops can have inadequate cooling, causing the CPU to slow.  It's possible the passmark results were done quickly (not giving the system time to heat) or with cleaner fans.  When I used to run large experiments back in college I would sit my laptop on the AC vent and it had a 3x difference on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: collect more data and draw some conclusions. It appears that when comparing these two systems some conclusions can be drawn but they might not extend to the chipsets or the processors.

Reviewing the data in the original posting and the following measurements, it appears that for small data sets not only does the quad system's hyperthreading not significantly improve throughput, but that even going beyond 2 threads on a 4 core device does not improve throughput per unit of time, at least with these particular homogenous workloads. For large data sets it appears that hyperthreading reduces throughput per unit of time. Note the 2933 second result compared to an average of 1883 seconds (mean of 2032 and 1734).

The dual core hyperthreading is amazingly good, scaling well across the thread pool size dimension. The dual core also scaled well across the data set size dimension.

[image: data table]

All measurements are elapsed times. Other means can be inferred, for example 2032 and 1734 can be averaged.